# Why does Rashi say Avraham thought the angels were wayfarers?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, malach-angel, abraham, vayera

Rashi on Breishis 18:16

> And the men arose from there, and they looked upon Sodom, and Abraham went with them to escort them,

says

> **to escort them**: Heb. לְשַׁלְּחָם, to escort them. He thought that they were wayfarers

How could Avraham have thought they were just wayfarers, when just a few pesukim earlier in 18:10, one of the angels says

> And he said, "I will surely return to you at this time next year, and behold, your wife Sarah will have a son." And Sarah heard from the entrance of the tent, and it was behind him.

From that statement, it would be obvious to Avraham that he was not an ordinary human being, to make such promises.

Comment: The strangers were obviously not angels with ferry wings and halos. That is ridiculous. No, they would have been regular men. The prediction made was just that, a prediction. It happened to come true because G-d willed it.

Comment: As ^^^, it could have been a prediction or a wish / blessing that just excludes the term "I hope / wish", etc. If anything might have convinced Avraham that they were **not** angels it's that they ate his food. Even Rash"i, himself supports that idea stating that they pretended to be humans by eating (I guess to avoid offending Avraham's hospitality.) See the Rash"i on that verse that mentions their eating.

Comment: I don't think the surrounding context justifies such an explanation. For example, why does it say in pasuk 15 "And Sarah denied, saying, "I did not laugh," because she was afraid. And He said, "No, but you laughed""?  - Why was Sarah afraid of laughing at a prediction or a well-wish some regular wayfarer said that she happened to overhear?

Comment: @user9806 Sarah laughed because it seems that she doubted that this could happen. This demonstrates a lack or denial of God's promise or God's ability to perform such miracles. (I'm inferring that somehow, Avraham may not have relayed to her the conversation he had with God, in the previous chapter. That seems difficult to understand.)